# VB:Giving variables a name from values of other variables

Tags: vb.net, variables

I'd like to make a variable with it's name after anotherone's value.

Here's an example:

```
    While loopBool
        loopTimes = 0
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim [loopTimes] As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath() 
        End If
        'Some more stuff
    End While
```

I'd like the [loopTimes] be the value of the variable loopTimes but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need this? Additionally, why can't you use a dictionary?

Comment: Why not just use an array, or dictionary, or any of multiple collection types?  Even if you can create static variables from this, how would you reference them later?  Collections are made for exactly this purpose.

Comment: You can't change the naming of your variables at runtime. Also why would you want to do this since it is not visible to the user.

Comment: As an overview, what do you actually want the code to do?

Comment: Please give a high level overview of what you are trying to do. You don't just write code to write code. What's the purpose of the above?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to use a dictionary:

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
```

Then, you can add your strings to the dictionary:

```
While loopBool
    loopTimes = 0 'I'm assuming this is already declared somewhere?

    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If DialogResult.OK Then
        myDict(loopTimes) = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath() 
    End If
    'Some more stuff
End While
```

Comment: `loopTimes` will need to be incremented, otherwise the second time you try to add an entry you'll get a duplicate key exception.

Comment: @Tim No, it will just overwrite the value (you might be thinking of the `Add` method). I'm assuming the OP increments `loopTimes` somewhere in `'Some more stuff`, otherwise there isn't much of a point to this code.

Comment: You're right - I was thinking of when you call the `.Add` method, but you're referencing the entry directly with the key.  Sorry about that.

Comment: the "'Some more stuff" means code that I haven't written yet.