# I would like to be able to create a variable with a name contained in a string

Tags: vb.net

i am attempting to do this in order to create objects each with different names without defining a hundred or so names

for example

```
Dim Counter as integer = 1
Public Sub Create_OBJ
    Dim Val(counter) as new rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20) 
    counter +=1 
End Sub
```

if anyone has any other suggestions i'm all ears

Comment: You're trying to create a dictionary.

Comment: Or since it's an incremental integer key, a list

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB:Giving variables a name from values of other variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844009/vbgiving-variables-a-name-from-values-of-other-variables)

Comment: @Asad: This is not a duplicate of that question at all. There's no question here about how to dimension an array at runtime; this is a different question altogether.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a poor choice for the original question, but it's still far from the first time this has been asked. I'd vote to close myself, but I'm too lazy to go find a better duplicate (of which there are many).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I didn't say it wasn't a duplicate of *something*. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Take a look again. That question wasn't about dimensioning arrays at runtime, it was about creating an variable with a name partially defined by the value of another variable. That is exactly what is being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

You need a collection. I know you asked about strings, but your example is entirely integer-based. With that in mind, a List(Of Rectangle) seems like a good fit:

```
'Create the base list
Dim Rectangles As New List(Of Rectangle)()

'Add a new item
Rectangles.Add(New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20))

'Retrieve an item by number
Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangles(0)
```

If you need arbitrary numbers for the index, rather than incremental numbers, you might want a Dictionary(Of Integer, Rectangle):

```
'Create the base dictionary
Dim Rectangles As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Rectangle)()

'Add a new item
Rectangles.Add(101, New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20))
'or
Rectangles(101) = New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20)

'Retrieve an item by number
Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangles(101)
```

If you really need strings, use a Dictionary(Of String, Rectangle):

```
'Create the base dictionary
Dim Rectangles As New Dictionary(Of String, Rectangle)()

'Add a new item
Rectangles.Add("101", New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20))
'or
Rectangles("101") = New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20)

'Retrieve an item by key
Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangles("101")
```

Based on your example, I find it highly unlikely that this last one is appropriate, and if you still think you want strings it might be worth posting a follow-up question with more detailed code asking what's most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates how to do this with a list:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _listOfRectangles As New List(Of Rectangle)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' add items to the list
        _listOfRectangles.Add(New Rectangle(100, 100, 20, 20))
        _listOfRectangles.Add(New Rectangle(200, 200, 20, 20))
        _listOfRectangles.Add(New Rectangle(300, 300, 20, 20))

        Debug.Print("access an item in the list by index")
        With _listOfRectangles(0)
            Debug.Print("Top:{0} Left:{1} Height:{2} Width:{3}", .Top, .Left, .Height, .Width)
        End With

        Debug.Print("retrieve an item from the list and put it in a variable")
        Dim rzero As Rectangle = _listOfRectangles(0)
        Debug.Print("Top:{0} Left:{1} Height:{2} Width:{3}", rzero.Top, rzero.Left, rzero.Height, rzero.Width)

        Debug.Print("loop through all the rectangles")
        For Each r As Rectangle In _listOfRectangles
            Debug.Print("Top:{0} Left:{1} Height:{2} Width:{3}", r.Top, r.Left, r.Height, r.Width)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the output

```
access an item in the list by index
Top:100 Left:100 Height:20 Width:20
retrieve an item from the list and put it in a variable
Top:100 Left:100 Height:20 Width:20
loop through all the rectangles
Top:100 Left:100 Height:20 Width:20
Top:200 Left:200 Height:20 Width:20
Top:300 Left:300 Height:20 Width:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary

```
Dim dic as new Generic.Dictionary(of String, Rectangle)
dic("First")=New Rectangle(1,1,50,50)
dic("Second")=New Rectangle(2,2,1000,200)

Dim outDicValue as Rectangle = dic("First")
```